# How to monkeypatch sqlite database for tests purposes?

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, pytest, peewee

In ORM.py file:

```
from peewee import *
db = SqliteDatabase('database.db')

class Device(Model):
    uid = CharField(unique=True, max_length=17)

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

now in the test.py I would like to monkeypatch orginal database `database.db` with `test.db`

```
from _pytest.monkeypatch import MonkeyPatch

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def monkeysession(request):
    mp = MonkeyPatch()
    yield mp
    mp.undo()


@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def create_db(monkeysession, request):
    monkeysession.setattr(ORM, 'db', SqliteDatabase('test.db'))
```

But my error (peewee.OperationalError: table "device" already exists) suggest that monkeypatch failed

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#testing-peewee-applications

```
# tests.py
import unittest
from my_app.models import EventLog, Relationship, Tweet, User

MODELS = [User, Tweet, EventLog, Relationship]

# use an in-memory SQLite for tests.
test_db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')

class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Bind model classes to test db. Since we have a complete list of
        # all models, we do not need to recursively bind dependencies.
        test_db.bind(MODELS, bind_refs=False, bind_backrefs=False)

        test_db.connect()
        test_db.create_tables(MODELS)

    def tearDown(self):
        # Not strictly necessary since SQLite in-memory databases only live
        # for the duration of the connection, and in the next step we close
        # the connection...but a good practice all the same.
        test_db.drop_tables(MODELS)

        # Close connection to db.
        test_db.close()

        # If we wanted, we could re-bind the models to their original
        # database here. But for tests this is probably not necessary.
```

Comment: `test_database` has been removed from [test_utils](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#test-utils).

Comment: Check out the "Testing Peewee Applications" docs - there are solutions for testing covered in the databases section: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#testing-peewee-applications